# print_r on array set in view on cake just prints 'Array'

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am setting a array in my controller by:

```
$messages = array("Apples", "Oranges", "Pears");

$this->set('messages', "$messages");
```

However then in my View if I try to print the array with:

```
<?php
     print_r($messages);
?>
```

I just get the word 'Array' not the actual content of the array.

Trying to access elements of the array does not seem to work either, for example:

```
echo $messages[0];
```

gives 'A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove double quote from `$this->set('messages', "$messages");`

it should be

```
$messages = array("Apples", "Oranges", "Pears");

$this->set('messages', $messages);
```

and in view you can

```
<?php
     pr($messages);
?>
```

Comment: `pr()` maps to `print_r()` in Cake, but possibly even more useful is `debug()` which formats the outputted array and includes the line number where the print statement was included. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing true to print_r, and remove your quote from $messages.

```
$messages = array("Apples", "Oranges", "Pears");

$this->set('messages', $messages);
print_r($messages, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Prakash is right, remove the double quote in "`$messages`" let it be `$messages`. So you have `$this->set('$messages', $messages)` and in your view 
you can just use `<?php echo $messages[0] ?>` You should be able to see "Apples". 
Or `print_r $messages` will give you:

```
[0] => "Apples",
[1] => "Oranges",
[2] => "Pears"
```